# angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the code, i have included the angular files, even angular-route, but it is still giving the same error. i am tryin a very simple angular code and still it is giving me this error, can someone tell me where am i going wrong here. Thanks.

```
<title>Login</title>
<div></div>
<div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen animated fadeInDown">
<div>
<div></div>
<h3>Welcome to Login</h3>
</div>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
<a ng-show="failedattempt">
  <small>Wrong username or password</small></a>
<form role="form" class="m-t">
  <div class="form-group">
    <!--input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value='<%= csrfToken %>')-->
    <input type="email" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" required="true" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" required="true" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button><a href="/login/forgot/"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['$scope']);
app.controller("LoginCtrl", function($scope){
var url = "/login/";
$scope.failedattempt=false;
$scope.user = {
username:"",
password:""
};
$scope.submit = function($scope){
  $scope.failedattempt = true;
}});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any 404 errors in your browser console? Just to make sure you have all the required files in place

Comment: No I am not seeing any 404, i have included all the angular files i found, but still it is giving the same error.

Comment: Just copied your code to my VS and did an F5. I was able to see login page without any errors. I included only angular.js file as reference..

Comment: Were you able to figure out the solution? If yes can you please share it?

Comment: yeah i was able to, removing $scope from definition did the trick i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please use the following definition for app

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

There is no need to include '$scope' in the definition.